# RecordInvalid troubles when using field_for, validation failed even though property exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm currently working on a website on Rails 6.0 and Ruby 2.5. In short, the website is to connect a person in need with someone who can help, together with a description of the help needed.

There are 3 relevant models for this question, `person_in_need`,`district` and `help`. A `person_in_need` has_many `helps` and belongs_to a `district`. A `help` belongs_to one `district`, a `district` has_many `helps`.

Below is the form to sign up a new `person_in_need` together with the `help` they need.

```
<%= form_with model: @person_in_need, url: persons_in_need_index_path do |form| %>
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name%>
    <br>
    <%= form.label :phone_number %>
    <%= form.phone_field :phone_number %>
    <br>
    <%= form.fields_for :helps do |help_form| %>
        <%= help_form.label :districts_id %>
        <%= help_form.grouped_collection_select :districts_id, State.order(:name), :districts, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
        <br>
        <%= help_form.label 'What kind of help do you need?' %>
        <%= help_form.select :help_type, options_for_select(Help.help_types.keys), include_blank: true %>
        <%= help_form.label 'Describe' %>
        <%= help_form.text_area :description %>
    <% end %>
    <%= form.submit 'Post' %>
<% end %>
```

The controller

```
class PersonsInNeedController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @person_in_need = PersonInNeed.new
        @person_in_need.helps.new
    end

    def create
        @person_in_need = PersonInNeed.create!(person_in_need_params)
        @person_in_need.helps.first.person_in_need_id = @person_in_need.id
        if @person_in_need.save
          redirect_to root_path 
        else
          redirect_to new_persons_in_need_path
        end
    end

    private

    def person_in_need_params
      params.require(:person_in_need).permit(:name, :phone_number, helps_attributes: [:help_type, :description, :districts_id])
    end
end
```

Below are the logs

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"eUmMHFVFcpRsO7cGzP2nJ/MAkM/Q6IDA/oPUrWNL1bBox53MqGLnAtklO1s6FVppoX3c8E1IADAGND+Q/74FwA==", "person_in_need"=>{"name"=>"Sar", "phone_number"=>"012345", "helps_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"districts_id"=>"Dungun", "help_type"=>"food", "description"=>"need rice"}}}, "commit"=>"Post"}

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Helps district must exist):
```

When I try to save the data, it returns the above error in the logs, I suspect it might have something to do with how I name my objects in the grouped_select_form, but playing around with that had no effect. I can see that the district is there in to logs, so why does it say it doesn't exist? Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

After reading through the Rails documentation, I added `validates_presence_of :user` to my Help model and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<%= help_form.grouped_collection_select :districts_id, State.order(:name), :districts, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
```

with

```
<%= help_form.grouped_collection_select :districts_id, State.order(:name), :districts, :id, :name, :name, include_blank: true %>
```

**EDIT:**
Could you please, also, add `:id` in strong parameters of `helps_attributes`, like this:

```
helps_attributes: [:id, :help_type, :description, :districts_id]
```

Comment: Thanks Sohail, but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error

Comment: updated my answer.. could you post the new logs after making these changes..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I read through the Rails documentation and added `validates_presence_of :user` to my Help model.